# Opposit letters with sed -r?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a text with random alphabetic characters and I want to change every character to his opposit one. 
ex. i have a character z, i change it in to a, b to y etc. 
I can't really find a better way to do this unless i do

```
sed -r -e 's/a/z/' -e 's/b/y/' ... 's/z/a/'
```

Is there a way to do this in a more simple way?

I just want to use the -r option in sed. 
Using the y command maybe?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or something? A [nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068264/unix-sed-command-reversed-alphabet) was submitted just an hour ago. BTW, they're both dups of [How can I get sed to change all of the instances of each letter only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886943/how-can-i-get-sed-to-change-all-of-the-instances-of-each-letter-only-once).

Comment: Yes it is, looks like we have trouble finding it. I think the solution is sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba/'

Answer (score 2):

`tr` is easier, 
e.g. for lowercase chars

```
$ z_a=$(echo {z..a} | tr -d ' '); echo adfa alfja | tr a-z $z_a
zwuz zouqz
```

the detour to create `z-a` is required since `tr` can't handle *"reverse collating sequence order"*.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a sed solution, but this seems a simple, straight forward use of perl:

```
cat input_file | perl -ple 's/(.)/chr(25-ord($1)+ord("a")*2)/eg'
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but this is a [UUoC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/3282436) (Useless Use of Cat).

Comment: yes, but I didn't know where the input was really coming from. It could be echo, or whatever, so I just left it alone.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` comes, one way is like this:

```
sed -r 'y/'"$(echo {a..z})"'/'"$(echo {z..a})"'/' file
```